# C# if array element does not exist in text file append the element in the file

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application in C# that contains a string array (string[]) with few elements and a file with text stored line-by-line. Now I want to loop through the array to see if the array element already exists in the file, if not write the array element to the end of the file. However, I cannot get the logic right.

Comment: Code? Do you have it?

Comment: what you exactly want,post your code

Comment: File.ReadLines(filePath) will get you the lines of the file in an IEnumerable. Make use of Enumerable.Except to get the differencies and File.AppendAllLines to write them back to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.AppendAllLines(filePath,stringArray.Except(File.ReadLines(filePath)));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, just a single line of code does all what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
string [] array ={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
string [] fromfile =File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
List<string>toadd = new List<string>();
foreach(string s in array){
    bool found =false;
    foreach(string fs in fromfile){
        if(fs==s){
         found =true;
            break;
        }
        if(found){
            toadd.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
File.AppendAllLines("file.txt",toadd);
```

**PS : dont forget :**

```
using System.IO;//for the file
using System.Collections.Generic; // for the list (toadd)
```